# What are keras checkpoint files, and can I safely delete them?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My working Keras directories have files in them called "checkpoint".  I did not knowingly create them.  My workflow is typically to save off weights for models that are working well, e.g. `model.save_weights('bob')`.  Once in a while I have saved entire models. Other than that I am not trying to save anything. Where might these be coming from, and can I clean them out without risking loss of anything?

Comment: Aren't you using `ModelCheckpoint` callbacks?

Comment: Or those checkpoints belong to the jupyter notebook?

Comment: No, not using ModelCheckPoint or Jupyter notebooks.  I'm working interactively in Spyder (ipython).  The checkpoint files just say "model_checkpoint_path: <blah>" and "all_model_checkpoint_paths: <blah>".  The paths are model weights files.

Comment: Never saw this.... I believe it's ok to delete. Move to another place and check if Keras will complain.

Comment: you are probably using tf.keras instead of keras?

Comment: Yes, I'm using tf.keras.